# QnA Maker Bot working in Teams private chats, but no answers when mentioned in team

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

I configured a knowledge base at qnamaker.ai, published it, and created a bot using Azure Bot Service.

In Teams, I created a new bot app and associated it with the deployed bot. The bot is allowed for private chats, group chats, and teams.

- If I'm in a private chat and "ask" it "deploy cosmosdb", it comes back with the correct answer.
- If I'm using the bot in a team, by mentioning it "@CS Bot deploy cosmosdb", it doesn't know the anwer.
- If I mention the bot in the private chat, I see the same behaviour: no answer.

But to talk to the bot it MUST be mentioned, so where's the problem here?

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to Hilton's answer below, I noticed that when you download the bot source code (in my case, it's a dotnet core project), the README.MD file states this issue **and how to fix it**:

> Microsoft Teams channel group chat fix
>
> - Goto `Bot/QnABot.cs`
> - Add References
>
>   ```
>   using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
>   using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
>   ```
> - Modify `OnTurnAsync` function as:
>
>   ```
>   public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
>       {
>           // Teams group chat
>           if (turnContext.Activity.ChannelId.Equals(Channels.Msteams))
>           {
>               turnContext.Activity.Text = turnContext.Activity.RemoveRecipientMention();
>           }
>
>           await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
>
>           // Save any state changes that might have occurred during the turn.
>           await ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
>           await UserState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
>       }
>   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the text that comes back in the 1st message, it will be "deploy cosmosdb". In the 2nd message though, it will be "CS Bot deploy cosmosdb" which the QnAMaker is struggling to parse. What you want to do, before passing the query text to QnAMaker, is to remove the "@" mention entirely from the text.

This is a common issue, so the Bot Framework already has a method to deal with this. You haven't mentioned what platform you're developing on, but here is a link for dotnet to the [RemoveRecipientMention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.schema.activityextensions.removerecipientmention?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable) method. I'm pretty sure there's an equivalent on Node, etc.

The final effect would be to convert your Activity's Text to be the same in both cases, which would result in the same response from QnAMaker.

Comment: That's exactly it. I just figured it out, too by debugging the bot locally. It's a shame this is happening because it's advertised as "no code". Only after downloading the bot's source and digging into the request, one would find out.

Comment: The problem I have now, is that I can't modify the incoming text before it gets passed on because the code is using `BotFrameworkHttpAdapter`

Comment: I'm not sure how BotFrameworkHttpAdapter should be the issue - it looks like you might need to dig around more. The code you're looking for is probably inside a class with "Dialog" in the name

Comment: Oh my goodness! How could I miss this? If you download the source code (.net core) project of the bot, the README.MD even mentions this issue under "Microsoft Teams channel group chat fix"! I'll update my question with this finding.

Comment: It's not that this couldn't _easily_ be mentioned somewhere in QnA Maker or on the Channel's blade when enabling Teams...

Comment: true, but it's a fine line, because actually QnA Maker is often included in already-existing bots (i.e. bots that are doing other things as well). I've got a few scenarios like that, where "QnA" is just one of the features of the bot, so this downloadable code is just a starting point, and you'd need broader bot knowledge anyway for the other functionality